# Dynamic offset in v-tour

Tags: vue.js

We implemented the vue-tour on our project but having a problem in making it dynamic for the other devices.

For example in my current setup, it is okay but if it is another device, you need to scroll up.

See my example tour:

```
{
    target: '.v-step-purchase-orders-2',
    header: {
        title: 'Create a Purchase Order - Purchase Order Details',
    },
    content: `Fill up with the appropriate Purchase Order Details.`,
    offset: -350,
    params: {
        placement: 'top'
    }
}
```

Question: Is it possible to make it dynamic?